# How to investigate into memory leaks in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, instruments, retain-cycle

I have created a simple flow to test memory in ios app. I have two view controllers in a navigation stack. I am showing an alert in the first view controller to allow user to move to the next one. Following is the code I am using.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelInfo: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func showNextScreen(_ sender: Any) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Go to next screen?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { [unowned self] (action) in

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNextScreen", sender: nil)

        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { [unowned self] (action) in

            self.labelInfo.text = "You did not move to next screen"
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } 

}
```

Having gone through the resources mentioning that there should not be a strong reference cycle, I have used ***unowned self*** in the code. Checking the leaks in the *Instruments*, I got the following graph.

[image]

The graph shows no leaks as indicated by green tick marks. However, as I move back and froth between the two view controllers, the memory usage graph is being increased. What might be causing this increase in memory usage (**first question**)?

Next, I also checked the effects replacing ***unowned self*** with ***self***. The result I got is the same as before. This suggests there is no strong reference. How do we determine existence of strong retain cycle with reference to this example (**second question**)?

[image]

Comment: how do you get back from the 2nd VC

Comment: @MohmmadS I use the back button of the navigation controller

Comment: @Sujal using a navigation controller ?

Comment: For me the easiest and most immediate way to see if view controllers deallocate is to put a print line in `deinit`. In my projects I have a `BaseViewController` class which calls `Utils.debugPrint("\(self) deinitialized")` in `deinit` method. And all my VC's are subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your second question.

With instruments aside, your code is segueing a `UIViewController` and dismiss it if simple as that, let us not think about retain cycles just yet.

**[Strong vs Weak vs Unowned](https://www.appcoda.com/memory-management-swift/) –**

1- Usually, when a property is being created, the reference is strong unless they are declared weak or unowned.

2- With the property labelled as weak, it will not increment the reference count

3- An unowned reference falls in between, they are neither strong nor or type optional
Compiler will assume that object is not deallocated as the reference itself remain allocated.

**[What](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19892274/8192960) is retain cycle:**

> Unless there is some other reference to the parent or child, they both become orphaned. But the retain cycle between the parent and child prevent either from 
>   being released and they become wasted memory.
>
> A child should never retain a parent. If anything, use a weak
>   reference in the child to maintain a reference to the parent.

Now lets take a look on what you have, you are using `UINavigationController & segue`, well the `UINavigationController` is a LIFO stack, also according to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

> A navigation controller is a container view controller that manages one or more child view controllers in a navigation interface. In this type of interface, only one child view controller is visible at a time.

So checking your `UIViewController` `deinit` function i think you would have no problem telling that the reference deallocated.

Now lets try to look to something else in the `UIAlertAction` you have this `[unowned self]`.

**[When to use unowned self or weak self](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24320474/8192960)**

> The only time where you really want to use [unowned self] or [weak
>   self] is when you would create a strong reference cycle. A strong
>   reference cycle is when there is a loop of ownership where objects end
>   up owning each other (maybe through a third party) and therefore they
>   will never be deallocated because they are both ensuring that each
>   other stick around.
>
> In the specific case of a closure, you just need to realize that any
>   variable that is referenced inside of it, gets "owned" by the closure.
>   As long as the closure is around, those objects are guaranteed to be
>   around. The only way to stop that ownership, is to do the [unowned
>   self] or [weak self]. So if a class owns a closure, and that closure
>   captures a strong reference to that class, then you have a strong
>   reference cycle between the closure and the class. This also includes
>   if the class owns something that owns the closure.

And as you said switching both `[unowned self]` and `[self]` did nothing.

Now the first question,

Well instruments leak checks are simple its a simply compare the significant increases in memory in the period of time, and compares it all to each others based on whats going on, this is not a 100% description but close, so whenever that green tick pops up it means you passed the test. doesn't mean 100% you are safe yet, you can visually see the allocation in the bottom section of instrument, observe the values changes **(increasing/ decreasing)** .. if something in increasing without ever decreasing, i think you found you problem.

Looking into your case i don't think you would find one

Comment: Adding similar alertcontroller code in the second viewcontroller, I could get the difference using self, unowned self. And, I could also generate the case Instruments showed no leaks yet the object allocation was increasing (https://imgur.com/a/Ys1D6QF)
I guess in my previous code, since my initial view controller does not get deinitialised, I was not able to see the effect.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Edit Scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics` 
Now tick `Malloc stack` like the screenshot. [image: Memory debug config] After doing that, rebuild and run . Now open `Debug memory graph`, you will see purple icon on the list of your class where memory leak has occurred. see this screenshot [image: Memory Debug Graph] Example Repo with memory leak is [Swift Memory Leak Demo](https://github.com/lvjian700/swift-memory-leaks-demo) Here is the view for memory leak with real example with the attached repo [image: Real Example picture with memory leak] 
**You can follow the same procedure on your project to identify the memory leak**